# Apace CXF - How to generate java classes in a specific root package?

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf-client

this works "fine" when generating the .java:

**"C:\Program Files\apache-cxf-3.5.2\bin\wsdl2java.bat" -client  http://localhost:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl**

but it generates many (100+) packages, all in different roots.

It I try instead:
**wsdl2java.bat -p com.test -client  http://localhost:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?wsdl**

I get some thousands time this error:

*WSDLToJava Error: http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?xsd=xsd24 [0,0]: Due dichiarazioni causano un conflitto nella classe ObjectFactory.
http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?xsd=xsd39 [0,0]: (Relativo allerrore riportato sopra) Questa è laltra dichiarazione.

http://virtual-1:10000/Framework.TbGes.TbGes?xsd=xsd39 [0,0]: Due dichiarazioni causano un conflitto nella classe ObjectFactory.*

I suppose wsdl2java is trying to generate all the classes DIRECTLY inside com.test, forgetting the  (sub)package name defined in the WDSL, and creating conflicts in case of classes with same name

Question:
is there any option, to tell wsdl2java to generate all classes in the package com.test, but also keeping the sub-packages as defined in the WDSL ?

Example:

omitting "-p com.test",  those are created:

*package webproxyobj_dospinaction.services.web.microarea;*

*package setuserinteractionmode.services.web.microarea;*

I would like that with "-p com.test", the same 2 are created like this:

*package **com.test**.webproxyobj_dospinaction.services.web.microarea;*

*package **com.test**.setuserinteractionmode.services.web.microarea;*

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation on https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html there is the option

```
-p [ wsdl-namespace= ] PackageName

Specifies zero, or more, package names to use for the generated code.
Optionally specifies the WSDL namespace to package name mapping.
```

So you probably have to add a mapping for every wsdl namespace you encounter in your wsdl. You should be able to use a regex-search-and-replace in the wsdl to generate that command line argument. However this might become very long and depending on your os and shell may exceed a command line lenght limit.

Comment: that does NOT help. I should write about 100+ times wsdl-namespace=com.something
Is there any to to specify the "root" (empty) wsdl-namespace ?


Someting like:


-p  wsdl-namespace=/ com.commonRoot


?

Comment: @Fabio2022 how often is your wsdl changing? If it does change only once in a while you only need to do this once and using regex search and replace in the wsdl can generate that command line argument and hence automate this.